# convert Json to AnyRef

Tags: scala, jackson

I am using Jackson to convert Json string to object. I have 2 methods to convert Seq[T] or T. For example:

```scala
def convert2Seq[T: ClassTag](str: String): Seq[T] = {
    val clazz = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass
    val listType = mapper.getTypeFactory.constructCollectionType(classOf[java.util.List[T]], clazz)
    val s: java.util.List[T] = mapper.readValue(str, listType)
    s.asScala
  }
```

```scala
  def convert[T: ClassTag](str: String): T = {
    val clazz = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass
    mapper.readValue(str, clazz).asInstanceOf[T]
  }
```

I have to use 2 methods to convert Seq[T] and T individually. Could we just use one method to cover both Seq[T] and T?

```scala
def convert[T: ClassTag](str: String): T
```

Comment: you should use more friendly to scala libraries like [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/) where this is possible

Comment: also, please check [scala module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) for jackson

Comment: Also `T` is not `AnyRef`